# using vs. typedef - is there a subtle, lesser known difference?

Tags: c++11, gcc, c++14, language-lawyer, clang++

### Background

Everybody agrees that

```
using <typedef-name> = <type>;
```

is equivalent to

```
typedef <type> <typedef-name>;
```

and that the former is to be preferred to the latter for various reasons (see Scott Meyers, Effective Modern C++ and various related questions on stackoverflow).

This is backed by [dcl.typedef]:

> A typedef-name can also be introduced by an alias-declaration. The identifier following the using keyword
>   becomes a typedef-name and the optional attribute-specifier-seq following the identifier appertains to that
>   typedef-name. Such a typedef-name has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the typedef specifier.

However, consider a declaration such as

```
typedef struct {
    int val;
} A;
```

For this case, [dcl.typedef] specifies:

> If the typedef declaration defines an unnamed class (or enum), the first typedef-name declared by the
>   declaration to be that class type (or enum type) is used to denote the class type (or enum type) for linkage
>   purposes only (3.5).

The referenced section 3.5 [basic.link] says

> A name having namespace scope that has not
>   been given internal linkage above has the same linkage as the enclosing namespace if it is the name of
>   [...]
>   an unnamed class defined in a typedef declaration in which the class has
>   the typedef name for linkage purposes [...]

Assuming the typedef declaration above is done in the global namespace, the struct `A` would have external linkage, since the global namespace has external linkage.

### Question

The question is now whether the same is true, if the typedef declaration is replaced by an alias declaration according to the common notion that they are equivalent:

```
using A = struct {
    int val;
};
```

In particular, does the type `A` declared via the alias declaration ("using") have the same linkage as the one declared via the typedef declaration?

Note that [decl.typedef] does not say that an alias declaration *is a* typedef declaration (it only says that both introduce a typedef-name) and that [decl.typedef] speaks only of a *typedef declaration* (not an alias declaration) having the property of introducing a *typedef name for linkage purposes*.
If the alias declaration is not capable of introducing a typedef name for linkage purposes, `A` would just be an alias for an anonymous type and have no linkage at all.

IMO, that's at least one possible, albeit strict, interpretation of the standard. Of course, I may be overlooking something.

This raises the subsequent questions:

- If there is indeed this subtle difference, is it by intention or is
  it an oversight in the standard?
- What is the expected behavior of compilers/linkers?

### Research

The following minimal program consisting of three files (we need at least two separate compilation units) is used to investigate the issue.

#### a.hpp

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP

#include <iosfwd>

#if USING_VS_TYPEDEF
using A = struct {
     int val;
};
#else
typedef struct {
     int val;
} A;
#endif

void print(std::ostream& os, A const& a);

#endif // A_HPP
```

#### a.cpp

```
#include "a.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void print(std::ostream& os, A const& a)
{
   os << a.val << "\n";
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "a.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.val = 42;
    print(std::cout, a);
}
```

### GCC

Compiling this with gcc 7.2 with the "typedef" variant compiles cleanly and provides the expected output:

```
> g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -DUSING_VS_TYPEDEF=0 a.cpp main.cpp
> ./a.out
42
```

The compilation with the "using" variant produces a compile error:

```
> g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -DUSING_VS_TYPEDEF=1 a.cpp main.cpp
a.cpp:4:6: warning: ‘void print(std::ostream&, const A&)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
void print(std::ostream& os, A const& a)
     ^~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
a.hpp:16:6: error: ‘void print(std::ostream&, const A&)’, declared using unnamed type, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
void print(std::ostream& os, A const& a);
     ^~~~~
a.hpp:9:2: note: ‘using A = struct<unnamed>’ does not refer to the unqualified type, so it is not used for linkage
};
 ^
a.hpp:16:6: error: ‘void print(std::ostream&, const A&)’ used but never defined
void print(std::ostream& os, A const& a);
     ^~~~~
```

This looks like GCC follows the strict interpretation of the standard above and makes a difference concerning linkage between the typedef and the alias declaration.

### Clang

Using clang 6, both variants compile and run cleanly without any warnings:

```
> clang++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -DUSING_VS_TYPEDEF=0 a.cpp main.cpp
> ./a.out
42

> clang++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -DUSING_VS_TYPEDEF=1 a.cpp main.cpp
> ./a.out
42
```

One could therefore also ask

- Which compiler is correct?

Comment: "*If there is indeed this subtle difference, is it by intention or is it an oversight in the standard?*" Here's a better question: *who cares?* The only reason to do `typedef struct` in C++ is for compatibility with C. And therefore, there's *never* a reason to do `using A = struct...`, whether it is legal or not.

Comment: Of course it results in an error, you have `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: Linkage refers to function or variable, *not* struct or class. Really the first time I heard "linkage of a struct". http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Linkage

Comment: @liliscent You're reading C documentation. What linkage means in C is different from what it means in C++.

Comment: @Nicolas Bolas. I agree 100% with you in saying that there is no reason to do `using A = struct ...` in C++. There is not even a reason to do `typedef struct ... A` unless you include headers from  C or have your headers included from C. However, I do care, because I have seen people doing both (unnecessarily) and claiming they are equal.

Comment: Confirmed both versions also work in Visual Studio 2017 Community version 15.5.5 cl version 19.12.25835 with Level 4 warnings on and treat warnings as errors on. Considering that now the majority of the major compilers do not consider `using A = struct...` an error I would agree that this is a bug in GCC.

Answer (score 11):

This looks to me like a bug in GCC.

> Note that [decl.typedef] does not say that an alias declaration is a typedef declaration

You're right, [dcl.dcl]p9 gives a definition of the term *typedef declaration* which excludes *alias-declaration*s. However, [dcl.typedef] does explicitly say, as you quoted in your question:

> 2 A *typedef-name* can also be introduced by an *alias-declaration*. The *identifier* following the `using` keyword becomes a *typedef-name* and the optional *attribute-specifier-seq* following the *identifier* appertains to that *typedef-name*. **It has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the `typedef` specifier.** [...]

"The same semantics" doesn't leave any doubt. Under GCC's interpretation, `typedef` and `using` have different semantics, therefore the only reasonable conclusion is that GCC's interpretation is wrong. Any rules applying to typedef declarations must be interpreted as applying to alias-declarations as well.

Comment: A typedef-name is one thing, a typedef declaration is another. An alias-declaration introduces a typedef-name, but is not a typedef declaration. The latter is defined very precisely in the standard as a declaration that contains the keyword `typedef`. There are many places in the standard that talk about "a typedef declaration or *alias-declaration*" (note hyphenation, italics, and usage of "a", I have copied them precisely from the draft standard).

Comment: @n.m. Huh, I missed the definition of the term "typedef declaration". Good point, I found it now. But there are many places that talk only of a typedef or a typedef declaration where it's beyond doubt that alias-declarations should be included, for instance [basic.types]p6, [dcl.fct]p10, [class.mem]p1. Will edit.

Comment: Perhaps not all of the standard was updated correctly to use alias-declaration when appropriate, but the intent to separate the two notions is clear.

Comment: @n.m. Yeah, agreed, so I removed that part from my answer, it doesn't affect my conclusion.

Comment: Though the passage that says "Such a typedef-name has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the typedef specifier" leaves me puzzled. If they have the same semantics, why not just call alias-declaration a typedef declaration too?

Comment: I've filed a GCC bug just in case: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99931

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the standard is unclear on this.

On one hand,

> **[dcl.typedef]** A *typedef-name* can also be introduced by an *alias-declaration*. [...] Such a *typedef-name* has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the `typedef` specifier.

On the other hand, the standard clearly separates the notions of typedef declaration and *alias-declaration* (the latter term is a grammar production name, so it is italicised and hyphenated; the former is not). In some contexts it talks about "a typedef declaration or *alias-declaration*", making them equivalent in these contexts; and sometimes it talks solely about "a typedef declaration". In particular, whenever the standard talks about linkage and typedef declarations, it only talks about typedef declarations and does not mention *alias-declaration*. This includes the key passage

> **[dcl.typedef]** If the typedef declaration defines an unnamed class (or enum), the first *typedef-name* declared by the declaration to be that class type (or enum type) is used to denote the class type (or enum type) for linkage
>   purposes only.

Note the standard insists on the **first** *typedef-name* being used for linkage. This means that in

```
typedef struct { int x; } A, B;
```

only `A` is used for linkage, and `B` is not. Nothing in the standard indicates that a name introduced by *alias-declaration* should behave like `A` and not like `B`.

It is my opinion that the standard is insufficiently clear in this area. If the intent is to make only typedef declaration work for linkage, then it would be appropriate to state explicitly in [dcl.typedef] that *alias-declaration* does not. If the intent is to make *alias-declaration* work for linkage, this should be stated explicitly too, as is done in other contexts.

Comment: In a typedef-declaration that declares only a single typedef-name, which an alias-declaration is supposedly equivalent to, a typedef-name can only be the first typedef-name though.

Comment: @hvd We're trying to figure out whether we can treat *alias-declaration* as a kind of typedef declaration. Your reasoning seems to assume the very thing we're trying to establish.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm assuming, that's what's in your answer already. I was responding to the bit where you suggested that `using B = struct { int x; };` could be treated as declaring `B` the way it's declared in `typedef struct { int x; } A, B;`.