# Error defining an unnamed structure in c++

Tags: c++, struct, typedef, using, unnamed-class

I'm having a problem with my code, even my professor has no idea why this is the case.

He wants me to define the structure with `using Persontype= struct{};` and not a normal definition of a structure. I don't understand why or what is the difference.

he also don't want us to include the .cpp file in main.

Normal definition of a struct works fine but not with this.

**the error**

```
In file included from ...\LABOR1TEST\main.cpp:3:
...\LABOR1TEST\test.hpp:12:6: warning: 'void test(const std::vector<<unnamed struct> >&)' used but never defined
 void test(std::vector<PersonType> const &_Personen);
      ^~~~
[100%] Linking CXX executable LABOR1TEST.exe
CMakeFiles\LABOR1TEST.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
.../LABOR1TEST/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `test(std::vector<._56, std::allocator<._56> > const&)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\LABOR1TEST.dir\build.make:120: LABOR1TEST.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/LABOR1TEST.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:102: CMakeFiles/LABOR1TEST.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:137: LABOR1TEST] Error 2
```

here is my code

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "test.hpp"

int main() {

    PersonType p;
    p.Name = "Max";
    std::vector<PersonType> TEMPVEC;
    TEMPVEC.push_back(p);
    TEMPVEC.push_back(p);
    test (TEMPVEC);
    return 0;
}
```

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "test.hpp"
void test(std::vector<PersonType> const &_Personen)
{
    for (auto const  &i : _Personen)
    {
    std::cout << i.Name << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and my test.hpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#ifndef LABOR1TEST_TEST_HPP
#define LABOR1TEST_TEST_HPP

using PersonType = struct {
    std::string Name;
};
void test(std::vector<PersonType> const &_Personen);
#endif //LABOR1TEST_TEST_HPP
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(LABOR1TEST)

set(CMAKE_C++_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(LABOR1TEST main.cpp test.cpp test.hpp)
```

Comment: You need to link `test.cpp` too. Please show you CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I have changed the question now. + He does not want us to include test.cpp in main

Comment: Linking and including are different things.

Comment: @M.M It's interesting that behavior differs between compilers. `clang++` works for me, but not `g++`. Aren't you on Mac by any chance and have `g++` aliased to `clang++`?

Comment: @yeputons I thought `using T = .....;` was meant to behave identically to the equivalent `typedef`. Check the standard now

Comment: @M.M Wow, it's equivalent, but yields different results on my compiler. Interesting.

Comment: @yeputons ok, it's in C++17 [basic.link]/4.3 which says that an unnamed class defined in a *typedef-declaration* behaves for linkage purpose as if the class had the typedef name.  So perhaps g++ is taking this literally and only applying that paragraph to `typedef` and not `using` ?  I doubt that was the intent of the language, probably that text was written before `using` was even added to the language and never been revisited

Comment: @yeputons [dcl.typedef]/2 says explicitly "Such a typedef-name has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the typedef specifier."   So I would tend to call this a g++ bug, although technically the standard is defective in that it gives contradictory requirements

Comment: @MommeSherif congratulations on discovering a defect in the Standard and a possible g++ bug. Not everyone can say they have done that :)

Comment: @M.M Look what I've found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48613758/using-vs-typedef-is-there-a-subtle-lesser-known-difference

Comment: @yeputons Looks like I have to withdraw my congratulation to OP. And should really close as duplicate

Comment: Wow that's an old problem! , i hope it gets fixed soon. Sad that's I was not the first xD .. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### My interpretation

`using PersonType = struct { ..... };` on a top-level will generate a different anonymous type in each translation unit (`.cpp` file, for simplicity) and then give it a name of `PersonType` in each translation unit. It does not matter that this statement happens inside `test.hpp`, all `#include`s are handled by preprocessor and do not matter when dealing with types.

So, `PersonType` in two translation units (`main.cpp` and `test.cpp`) actually refer to different types. In effect, `main.cpp` expects to find `test(vector<PersonType> const &)` with one `PersonType`, and `test.cpp` only provides `test(vector<PersonType> const&)` with another `PersonType`, hence the linkage error.

### Is it a GCC bug?

You can see the error better if you get rid of templates and try compiling the following two translation units together:

```cpp
using Foo = struct {};
void test(Foo);
int main() {
    Foo f;
    test(f);
}
```

```cpp
using Foo = struct {};
void test(Foo) {
}
```

My GCC tells me the following:

```
a.cpp:2:6: error: 'void test(Foo)', declared using unnamed type, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
    2 | void test(Foo);
      |      ^~~~
a.cpp:1:7: note: 'using Foo = struct<unnamed>' does not refer to the unqualified type, so it is not used for linkage
    1 | using Foo = struct {};
      |       ^~~
a.cpp:2:6: warning: 'void test(Foo)' used but never defined
    2 | void test(Foo);
      |      ^~~~
```

However, replacing `using Foo = struct {};` with `typedef struct {} Foo;` apparently works, as well as switching from my GCC to my Clang.

M.M from comments suggested that `typedef` should work because of [[basic.link]/4.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#4.3)

> a named class ([class.pre]), or an unnamed class defined in a typedef declaration in which the class has the typedef name for linkage purposes ([dcl.typedef]);

It may get interpreted by GCC too literally(?) to exclude `using`, although [[dcl.typedef]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef#2) says that the name introduced by `using` should have the same semantics as `typedef`.

Surprisingly, [it was even asked on StackOverflow before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48613758/using-vs-typedef-is-there-a-subtle-lesser-known-difference)!

### Regarding your problem

> He wants me to define the structure with using Persontype= struct{}; and not a normal definition of a structure.

If the text above is true, that's quite a strange requirement. It makes it impossible to link different translation units against `PersonType`. I'm wondering what's the rationale behind, maybe you're not supposed to actually expose `PersonType` beyond a single translation unit? Consider consulting with your TA or a professor.

Comment: Actually, after a bit of research, I'm not so sure in my interpretation: g++ and clang++ yield different results for me, as well as changing between `using PersonType = struct {.....}` and `typedef struct {.....} PersonType`. Needs further investigation.

Comment: thats true i tried it with the visual studio c++ compiler in the toolchain of cmake (in clion) and it worked normal! And doesn't work in Linux either with the g++ or gcc compiler

Comment: Thanks man! you are a hero, i will show him this tomorrow and ask him again. Really thanks a lot !!!!